# Word VBA MoveUp Troubles

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using the following script to increase a `Selection` in MS Word.

```
 Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=10, Extend:=wdExtend
```

The outcome varies depending of the current Page View, results are as follows:

If the Page View is set such that only one Column of pages is displayed then it Extends the `MoveUp` perfectly.

[image]

If the Page View to is set such that there are two or more pages being viewed along side each other and you are in the second row of pages or further, then one `MoveUp` `Count` at the top of the page selects the entire previous page.

[image]

If the Page View to is set such that there are two or more pages being viewed along side each other, and you are in the top row of pages then one `MoveUp` `Count` stops at the top of the page.

[image]

Is this a defect in the operation or am I not using the `MoveUp` function incorrectly?

Comment: Something else you might consider, if the "lines" are actually all paragraphs, as in your illustration: Rather than use Selection, use a Range object. That's not dependent on screen layout, as lines are. Something like: Dim rng as Word.Range : Set rng = Selection.Range : rng.MoveStart wdParagraph, -10 : rng.Select

Comment: Have always been using `wdLine` so I will try the `paragraph ` tomorrow. Thanks. My will will how it operates when it comes across an actual paragraph or a Table

Comment: I'll be curious to learn if/how it works for you :-) But please remember to test using a RANGE object, not selection.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have played around with it. Using `wdParagraph` as a Unit in stead of `wdLine` seemed to be better but the`Extend` part of it changes the outcome. I will add it  as a answer. For me the `wdLine` still works better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done, as a work around.

In the Project is set the Page View to 100% as part of the DocumentNew Sub. Which then sets the view to 100% and all the script will be executed before the user has access to the document.

In Project - Microsoft Word Objects - ThisDocument

```
Private Sub Document_New()

InitialScreen.Show

'If the view is set to View Pages Side by side it messes up the Move Selection
'WhenInserting the Group Headings
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 100

End Sub
```

As per a comment, I played around a little with the `wdParagrpah`. He are the results:

`wdParagraph`
does not worry about the page layout, which is good

`Extend = wdExtend`

Count starts from line above selection
Does not include the selection
Sees each table row as 1

`Extend = wdMove`

Count starts from line above the selection
Sees the each table row as the number of column
Paragraph markers basically uses the paragraph marker for each count
if there is a "Shift + Enter" (New Line, Not New Paragraph) then it sees it as 
one paragraph, obviously